# Parsing a web page after a Login into an iOs application

Tags: html, iphone, ios, parsing, hpple

I am trying to parse a website that is after a Login into an iOS application, parsing the HTML tags works fine with hpple but I don`t know how to "pass through" the Login.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

To login to a website, you need to send a POST request. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) makes it very easy to do this.

With AFNetworking:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"usernameKey": @"theUsernameForTheWebsite",@"passwordKey": @"thePasswordForWebsite"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/loginpage.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

To adapt the above example for your use take a look at this example HTML form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputUsername" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" name="inputUsername">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The `action` attribute on the `<form>` element will have a **relative url** to the place where you need to send your post request. ("" in this goes to the current page that has this form on it). Notice in the example the `name` attribute on the `<input>` elements. That attribute would be the key to use in the `parameters` `NSArray` for the username and password password.

After you login, cookies will be set and handled automatically and you can then use AFNetworking to send more GET requests to get pages that require login.

Note that the example was using AFNetworking 2.0 (released today, I believe).

Comment: @user2824788 responseObject will contain a NSData object. Get the string with `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:responseData.bytes]`